# To see all the components in a form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

Well,i have a weird question to ask,sometimes when designing a form and using lots of controls and panel layers,some controls get sort of "lost" in the form.They get behind the docked panels etc.Is there a window or something like that in visual studio to see all of the components used in the form so i could find the unused components?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the Document Outline: `Ctrl+W, U`

Comment: Wow! I had no idea this existed.  We run into this situation a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  You can check the designer file for the form, or you can use the property window's control dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right-click on a Control, and you'll get a "Select..." to select the Controls under it.

Also, right-click and then "Send to back". (But don't forget to "Bring to front" when you're done, if that's needed.)